# Работа с LibreOffice из C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, libre-office

Потребовалось управлять libreoffice writer/calc из visual c# wpf.
C Microsoft Word/Excel это уже делал через Microsoft.Office.Interop
Скиньте, пожалуйста, ссылку на пошаговую инструкцию, как связать visual c# wpf и libreoffice.
Описание функций и, если можно, примеры.
Запустить, открыть файл (или создать новый) изменить содержимое, сохранить.
Как я понимаю, все должно быть примерно так как с Microsoft.Office.Interop
Помогите, кто чем может!